# What is the difference between the ‘customs & immigration’ and ‘entry’ tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The ‘entry’ tag has no definition associated with it. Intuitively I can see there must be a difference between ‘customs & immigration’ and ‘entry’ but I’d be hard-pressed to put it into words. From questions I see on TSE I suspect that the former tag is used much more often than the latter; assuming that’s the case, should the two be merged?

Comment: When was [tag:entry] created?

Comment: @JoErNanO I’m sorry, I’ve tried to find the creation date but no luck. It doesn’t appear under ‘Tag Info’, I don’t know where else to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just merged the two tags. Sadly, I did not manage to find the creation date for [entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entry).